# JUnit assertion null - using stubs and mocks

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

Here is my test method:

```
@Test
public void shouldReturnUser_whenPassedUser() {
    // given
    when(userStub.getUsername()).thenReturn(defaultName);
    when(userStub.getPassword()).thenReturn(defaultPassword);
    when(userStub.getEmail()).thenReturn(defaultEmail);

    // when
    User savedUser = userServiceBean.saveUser(userStub);

    // then
    assertNotNull(savedUser);
    verify(userRepository, times(1)).save(any(User.class));
}
```

Here is my setup:

```
 @Spy
@InjectMocks
private UserServiceBean userServiceBean;

@Mock
private UserRepository userRepository;

@Mock
private Principal principal;

@Mock
private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

@Mock
private User userStub;

private String defaultName = "user";
private  String defaultPassword = "password";
private String defaultEmail = "example@example.com";

@Before
public void init() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}
```

And here is my userService.saveUser method:

```
public User saveUser(User user) {
    User newUser = new User(user.getUsername(), user.getEmail(), passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
    return userRepository.save(newUser);
}
```

And my test results:

```
java.lang.AssertionError
at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:86)
at org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:41)
at org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull(Assert.java:712)
at org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull(Assert.java:722)
at com.doublemc.services.UserServiceBeanTest.shouldReturnUser_whenPassedUser(UserServiceBeanTest.java:93)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:237)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

Why does my method return null? I'm using a stubUser and I tell him exactly what to return to each getter (as I'm doing in my saveUser method) and it still returns null? How should I change that test to work?

Comment: Try to debug your code, with that you will see what exactly was not injected (it is what I suspect), then add this result here, it will help.

Comment: Btw. it's better to use real objects instead of mocks where possible. This makes sure you don't miss too much from reality. So I suggest to create a real `User` object instead of a mock with all its mocked methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to define the mock behaviour for the `userRepository` mock. So Mockito uses the default return value null for `save`.

Define the behaviour like this:

```
when(userRepository.save(any(User.class))).thenReturn(new User("saved name", "saved email", "saved password"));
```

Comment: Good catch. Adding some sample of what he should do it will make this answer way better `when(userRepository).save(.....` +1 anyway.

Comment: What do you mean by 'define mock behaviour'? Sorry, I'm very new to Mockito.

Comment: @doublemc Mocks are exactly what that - they can be used in place of "real" instances of classes, but they will do nothing unless you tell them to. So in this example, we're telling our mock userRepository to return a specific instance of User when we call the method 'save'. That's the behaviour we refer to in mocking. In other words, "when I call this method with these arguments, then return this object".